# JPA cascade persist - many to one unidirectional

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

I have a many to one relationship unidirectional and I am trying to persist a child entity i.e. SubscriptionEntity also expect that it should also persist Parent as I am using cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST

Background about relationships : SubscriptionEntity let you know which **user** is associated with which **business** and there are few more entity to like state and product which tells us **state** of subscription and what are the **product** associated with subscription. Subscription state is one to many bi-directional because subscription can move to many status throughout the membership on-hold, active, deactivate etc.. And similarly Subscription relation with product is one to many bi-directional as user can subscribe for one product or more than one.

We can't do bi-directional association between User and Subscription because user can have association with many businesses.

```
    public class SubscriptionEntity implements Domain, Serializable
    {
        @Column(name = "subscription2user")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        @JoinColumn(name = "subscription2user")
        private UserEntity user;

        @Column(name = "subscription2biz")
        @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "subscription2biz")
        private BusinessEntity business;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "subscription", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        private List<ProductSubscriptionEntity> subscribedProducts;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "subscription", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
        private List<SubscriptionStateEntity> state;
    }

public class UserEntity implements Domain, Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 755369097357065341L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "user_first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "user_last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "user_mobile")
    private BigInteger mobile;

    @Column(name = "user_password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "user_create_date")
    private Date createDate;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user2address")
    @Column(name = "user2address")
    private UserAddressEntity address;
}

public class SubscriptionStateEntity implements Domain, Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "subscription_state2subscription")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="subscription_state2subscription")
    protected SubscriptionEntity subscription;
}

public class ProductSubscriptionEntity implements Domain, Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "user_product_subscription2subscription")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_product_subscription2subscription")
    private SubscriptionEntity subscription;
}
```

Scenario : Business is already present but User is new, and association between user and subscription is also new. When I am trying to add new subscription getting below error. If User already present in DB then it work smoothly.

```
void addSubscription(final UserEntity user, final String businessID)
{
    final UserEntity userTemp = this.userDao.readUserByIdOrMobile(user.getId(), user.getMobile());
    if (null == userTemp)
    {
        user.setId(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        user.setCreateDate(DateUtil.getDateTimestamp());
    }
    final BusinessEntity business = getBusinessByID(businessID);
    SubscriptionEntity subscription = new SubscriptionEntity();
    subscription.setUser(user);
    subscription.setBusiness(business);

    super.getEm().persist(subscription);
}
```

> Caused by: 
>   org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityExistsException: Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ... ... REFERENCES
>   `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure this is working code? normally the Column is not used when you have JoinColumn. An annotation exception will be thrown

Comment: Yes its working code I am getting exception while persisting the Subscription.

Comment: In case of OpenJPA it works with JoinColumn. When we use Hibernate it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not given table and column mapping annotations on UserEntity entity.

Since you are not settimg the id for UserEntity, are you having the id generation strategy defined ? When you do not have the id set, there is no linking between subscription and user.

You can add the id generation strategy as auto increment using the annotation given below in the UserEntity on id field. This will generate id on creation.

GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private String id;

Comment: User table have id, firstName, lastName, mobile, emaild, address.
I am checking is user already present by mobile number if not then assigning id new UUID as shown below:

void addSubscription(final UserEntity user, final String businessID)
{
    final UserEntity userTemp =      this.userDao.readUserByIdOrMobile(user.getId(), user.getMobile());
    if (null == userTemp)
    {
        user.setId(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        user.setCreateDate(DateUtil.getDateTimestamp());
    }
  
}

Comment: Can you update your question with UserEntity class code ?

Comment: updated question with UserEntity, thanks for giving time for question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify any ID for the user entity, since the ID is String, it will create a UserEntity with ID "". Try to add some id generation strategy for the user entity ID, otherwise the newly created user is always the user which will cause this `EntityExistsException`.

P.s. the bi-directional association just means you can get entities from both sides. It doesn't have anything to do with your business logic.

Comment: I have updated my original question with below text was missed in initial post.

user.setId(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());

Comment: We are avoiding to use bi-directional association between UserEntity and SubscriptionEntity because if we pull user by any business then due to bi-directional association it will allow visibility of subscriptions associated with other business as well, which we don't want to expose.

Comment: OK, now I understand your point. If you are trying to set a new user to the new subscription, why are you passing the user to subscription?

Comment: I have a rest api which takes input of user object and business ID which indicates that we have to store new User and associate it with that business. Since user and business association are store in subscription table. Add subscription but user is also new so add it also.

Comment: this.userDao.createUser(userTemp);
this.subscriptionDao.createSubscribeUser(subscription); Also tried to create user first then user and business association but failed with same error.